# FFmpeg: How to decrease the volume for few seconds in the middle of audio file?

Tags: audio, command-line, ffmpeg

I have an audio file with 120 seconds duration. I want to make the volume muted from 80th second to 100th second using FFmpeg.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af "volume=0:enable='between(t,80,100)'" out.mp3
```